# Jekyll's sitemap plugin - exclude assets pages

Tags: jekyll, jekyll-extensions

I'm using [jekyll-sitemap](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-sitemap) plugin for Jekyll.

Is there a way to exclude .html files within the `assets` folder?
Some of them contain some HTML examples and I end up having things like the following in my sitemaps.xml, which doesn't make sense:

```
<url>
<loc>https://example.com/blog/assets/vanilla-lazyload/demos/with_picture.html</loc>
<lastmod>2017-11-18T15:05:22+01:00</lastmod>
</url>
```

Where `with_picture.html` is a demo file of a Javascript library, that comes with it when using `npm install` (and I can't be bother to remove those every time for every library)

[According to the docs](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-sitemap#exclusions), using `sitemap: false` in our front matter should solve it, but it doesn't seem to be working at all.

Because I do not have any front matter in those vendor files, I'm using the [Jekyll's Front Matter defaults method](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/#front-matter-defaults) to do so, but without success.

```
# in my _config.yml
defaults:
  - scope:
      path: 'assets/'
    values:
      sitemap: false
```

I also tried the following `path` without luck:

path: "assets"

Might it be that `path: 'assets'` wont' take into account subfolders?

Comment: found any solution to this? in my case, not even the simple front matter is working. :-|

Comment: I think I never did. I had to remove them manually.

Comment: by manually, do you mean `sitemap: false`? because it doesn't work for me (under https://ahoxus.org/pt/propostas/naturala/ source and sitemap are there if you wanna see it). still trying to figure out why. does it work for you? or what is "manually"?

Comment: Manually removing the entries that I don't like to be in the sitemap.

Answer (score 6):

If your Jekyll version is `v3.7.2` or higher and your `jekyll-sitemap` version is `v1.2.0` or higher, this should work:

```
defaults:
  -
    scope:
      path: 'assets/**'
    values:
      sitemap: false
```

The `**` will match any file in the `assets` directory or in any of its subdirectories.

[Here's the relevant section in the docs.](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-sitemap#exclusions)

Answer (score 2):

You can easily create your own sitemap without the plugin: Create a file called ‘sitemap.xml’ in your main jekyll folder, as in next to _post, _pages, and _includes.

All the file needs to contain is the following:

```
---
layout: null
---
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd" xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
  {% for post in site.posts %}
    <url>
      <loc>{{ site.url }}{{ post.url }}</loc>
      {% if post.lastmod == null %}
        <lastmod>{{ post.date | date_to_xmlschema }}</lastmod>
      {% else %}
        <lastmod>{{ post.lastmod | date_to_xmlschema }}</lastmod>
      {% endif %}
      <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
      <priority>1.0</priority>
    </url>
  {% endfor %}
  {% for page in site.pages %}
    {% if page.sitemap != null and page.sitemap != empty %}
      <url>
        <loc>{{ site.url }}{{ page.url }}</loc>
        <lastmod>{{ page.sitemap.lastmod | date_to_xmlschema }}</lastmod>
        <changefreq>{{ page.sitemap.changefreq }}</changefreq>
        <priority>{{ page.sitemap.priority }}</priority>
       </url>
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
</urlset>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your _config.yml file, add :

```
exclude :
 - assets/vanilla-lazyload/demos
```

Comment: I want to exclude everything within `assets`, as that's a folder in which I'll be adding different assets, each of them might contain HTML files. 
So I rather prefer not having to modify the _config.yml file every time I add a vendor asset.

Comment: If setting default config doesn't work (did you try `path: 'assets'` ?), I don't see another way.

Comment: I did. Same result. Nothing changed. The files still being included in the sitemap.

Comment: Nop, but you can test it yourself if you want. You'll most certainly get the same result.